# Swift error: Could not find an overload for '&&' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift, xcode6-beta6

I have been working on some tutorials for Swift.  I came across a TicTacToe tutorial that I'm trying to code using Xcode 6 Beta 6.  I'm getting the following error when I check the values in a dictionary:  Could not find an overload for '&&' that accepts the supplied arguments.  Here's my code.

```
var plays = [Int:Int]()

var whoWon = ["I":0,"you":1]
for (key,value) in whoWon {
if ((plays[6] == value && plays[7] == value && plays[8] == value) || 
    (plays[3] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[5] == value) || 
    (plays[0] == value && plays[1] == value && plays[2] == value) || 
    (plays[6] == value && plays[3] == value && plays[0] == value) || 
    (plays[7] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[1] == value) || 
    (plays[8] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[2] == value) || 
    (plays[6] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[2] == value) ||  // error appears on this line
    (plays[8] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[0] == value))  
 {
    userMessage.hidden = false
    userMessage.text = "Looks like \(key) won!"
 }
```

Comment: How do you break up something into subexpressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the full compiler output in the Report Navigator then you will see the
message

> note: expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time;
>   consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

which tells you how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the Issue Navigator tab.

Comment: Hey @Martin R I am working with this same tutorial and I'm a beginner, how would you go about breaking it into sub expressions?

Answer (score 1):

I was doing the same tutorial.
Seems to me a bit weird that it had to be broken up in subexpressions, but it did the trick, and as I read here: 
http://swiftlang.eu/community/34-xcode-6-beta-6-swift-can-t-handle-long-expressions/0

it might be due to a problem of Xcode.

Here's the rewritten function:

```
func checkForWin() {
    var whoWon = ["I": 0, "You": 1]
    for (key, value) in whoWon {
        var wonA = (plays[1] == value && plays[2] == value && plays[3] == value)
        var wonB = (plays[4] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[6] == value)
        var wonC = (plays[7] == value && plays[8] == value && plays[9] == value)
        var wonD = (plays[1] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[7] == value)
        var wonE = (plays[2] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[8] == value)
        var wonF = (plays[3] == value && plays[6] == value && plays[9] == value)
        var wonG = (plays[1] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[9] == value)
        var wonH = (plays[3] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[7] == value)

        if(wonA || wonB || wonC || wonD || wonE || wonF || wonG || wonH) {
                userMessage.hidden = false
                userMessage.text = "Looks like \(key) won!"
                resetBtn.hidden = false
                done = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why `var` instead of `let`? (I.E., won* could be constants, right?...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the parenthesis to "breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions".
This works in Xcode 6.4

```
 if (((plays[1] == value) && (plays[2] == value) && (plays[3] == value)) ||
     ((plays[4] == value) && (plays[5] == value) && (plays[6] == value)) ||
     ((plays[7] == value) && (plays[8] == value) && (plays[9] == value)) ||
     ((plays[1] == value) && (plays[4] == value) && (plays[7] == value)) ||
     ((plays[2] == value) && (plays[5] == value) && (plays[8] == value)) ||
     ((plays[3] == value) && (plays[6] == value) && (plays[9] == value)) ||
     ((plays[1] == value) && (plays[5] == value) && (plays[9] == value)) ||
     ((plays[3] == value) && (plays[5] == value) && (plays[7] == value))) {...}
```